surface area of trilobes and quadrolobes
I need to calculate surface area of trilobes and quadrolobes that is corresponding to a cylinder. For example ı have a 10cm diameter cylinder but what is the diameter of 1 cylinder in that trilobe and how can i calculate total surface area of it. same for quadrolobes

wouldn't it be defined by the length of the exposed curcusference?
